# Ideal (view)model design for this situation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I'm trying to wrap my brain around viewmodels and when it is appropriate to use them. I'd like an explanation of what to do in this situation:

Model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string firstName {set;get;}
    public string lastName {set;get;}
    public string City {set;get;}
    .... other junk
}
```

Controller:

```
IEnumerable<Person> model = db.Person
.Where(r => r.City == city)
.Select(r => new Person{ 
    firstName = r.firstName,
    lastName = r.lastName,
    something = r.something});
```

Now let's say my page allows a user to select a `city` that he would like to filter by. Additionally, I only want to display the `firstName` and `lastName`. Would this be the time to use a viewmodel? Previously I would have done something like this.

Viewmodel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string firstName {set;get;}
    public string lastName {set;get;}
    public string cityChoice {set;get;}
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cityList {set;get;}
}
```

I've come to the realization that since my query would return a type `IEnumerable<Person>`, then I would have a `cityList` for each row returned by the query. What would the better viewmodel be? My next thought is to make everything an `IEnumerable`:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> firstName {set;get;}
    public IEnumerable<string> lastName {set;get;}
    public IEnumerable<string> cityChoice {set;get;}
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> cityList {set;get;}
}
```

This doesn't seem like a smart choice at all. It just looks messy and implementation also look like it could be a pain.

In short, what is the best way to pass the least amount of data from a controller to a view while maintaining a `List<SelectListItem>`? I have seen implementations where the list is passed via `viewbag` or `viewdata` but that seems like pad practice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do TWO view models - one for the view, one for the data:

```
public class CitySelectionVM {
  public string SelectedCity {set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CityList {set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<PersonVM> PersonList {set;get;}
}
```

Additionally the second view model for the People specific data:

```
public class PersonVM
{
  public string FirstName {set;get;}
  public string LastName {set;get;}
}
```

Comment: This seems to the an efficient method. I'm curious if there are other ways to do this more effectively. What if you had many pages that show unique subsets of your table. You would need a VM for each one right?

Comment: Ideally yes.. Because otherwise it's starting to get confusing.